# Setting up new github repository - unknown switch `u'

Tags: github, repository

I am trying to setup a new repository on my existing GitHub account.

I followed the steps circled here:

[image]

When I run the command git push -u origin master, I get the following error:

error: unknown switch `u'

Any ideas as to the issue? Doing a Google search for this error didn't seem to cough-up anything useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems your git client is too old. Try to update it to most recent version:
http://git-scm.com/

Comment: It depends on your OS. Just follow the instruction: http://help.github.com/set-up-git-redirect

Comment: I downloaded the latest version and got this error too. So i doubt if it is too old.

Answer (score 6):

Ignore the error: unknown switch `u'

Try what they say here, http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/

```
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe that this:

```
$ git push -u origin master
```

...is equivalent to:

```
$ git push origin master
$ git config --add branch.master.remote origin
$ git config --add branch.master.merge refs/heads/master
```

So if you're running an older version of Git that doesn't support `-u` for `git push`, run that group of 3 commands instead.